# Induction Not Starting from $\boldsymbol{0}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I am reading the proof for the proposition below:

> For all $\boldsymbol{a},\boldsymbol{m},\boldsymbol{n} \in \mathbb{N}$, if $\boldsymbol{a} > \boldsymbol{0}$ and $\boldsymbol{m} < \boldsymbol{n}$ then $\boldsymbol{a} \cdot \boldsymbol{m} < \boldsymbol{a} \cdot \boldsymbol{n}$.

It is assumed that the following theorem can be used in the proof:

> For all $\boldsymbol{a},\boldsymbol{m},\boldsymbol{n} \in \mathbb{N}$, if $\boldsymbol{m} < \boldsymbol{n}$ then $\boldsymbol{a} + \boldsymbol{n} < \boldsymbol{a} + \boldsymbol{n}$.

The proof was constructed using mathematical induction, and the induction was conducted on $\boldsymbol{n}$. The author argued that the smallest $\boldsymbol{n}$ for $\boldsymbol{m} < \boldsymbol{n}$ is $\boldsymbol{m}^{+}$, so that the starting point for the induction should be $\boldsymbol{m}^{+}$ instead of $\boldsymbol{0}$. I am a little confused by this statement, although intuitively it makes sense. Below is my confusion.

To prove the theorem using mathematical induction, of course we should construct a set
\begin{equation}
A = \left\{\boldsymbol{n} \in \mathbb{N}: \boldsymbol{a} > \boldsymbol{0} \textrm{ and } \boldsymbol{m} < \boldsymbol{n} \textrm{ implies } \boldsymbol{a} \cdot \boldsymbol{m} < \boldsymbol{a} \cdot \boldsymbol{n}\right\},
\end{equation}
and try to prove $A = \mathbb{N}$ using the induction theorem ($\boldsymbol{0} \in A$ and for all $\boldsymbol{n} \in A$, $\boldsymbol{n}^{+} \in A$). In this case, $\boldsymbol{0} \in A$ is trivial, as $\boldsymbol{m} < \boldsymbol{0}$ has to be false. Then why did the author use $\boldsymbol{m}^{+}$ as the starting point for induction? Is it necessary to verify the first $\boldsymbol{n}$ where $\boldsymbol{m} < \boldsymbol{n}$ is true? Is it OK not to use $\boldsymbol{0}$ as the starting point for induction?

Comment: You may find Tobias Kildetoft's post on induction (for the abandoned MSE blog) interesting: https://math.blogoverflow.com/

Comment: There's nothing magical about $0$.  you can use any point you want.  If you can prove $P(k)\implies P(k+1)$ and you can prove $P(m)$ for some initial $m$ then you have proven $P$ for all $n \ge m$.  it doesn't matter *where* you start, you can bootstrap from there.  For example If I wanted to prove $n! > 40,000$ whenever $n \ge 8$ we can easily prove the induction step:  If $k! >40,000$ then $(k+1)!=(k+1)k! > (k+1)40,000 \ge 40,000$ and the proof only hinges on the initions step.  If $k=8$ then $k! =8! = 40,320 > 40,000$.  And our proof by induction is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given any integer $a,$ observe that the statement $P(n)$ holds for all integers $n \geq a$ if and only if the statement $P(m + a)$ holds for all integers $m \geq 0.$ Consequently, the Principle of Mathematical Induction can be invoked to show that (1.) if $P(n)$ holds for the integer $n = a$ and (2.) $P(n + 1)$ holds whenever $P(n)$ holds for some integer $n \geq a,$ then $P(n)$ holds for all integers $n \geq a.$ Ultimately, this says precisely that the base case for a proof by mathematical induction need not be the case that $n = 0.$